# I am trying to retrieve data from a Ruby cdn of the Pokemon API but I am struggling

Tags: ruby, rest, parsing, xmlhttprequest

Below is my Pokemon TCG API key

I have read the documentation but I cannot find a way to retrieve the data I need which is the images of each card in a set. If anyone can help with or give me any pointers on how to retrieve this I would greatly appreciate it.

https://github.com/PokemonTCG/pokemon-tcg-sdk-ruby/blob/master/README.md

This above is the link to the documentation on Github.

```
Pokemon.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
end

sets = Pokemon::Set.where(q: 'legalities.standard:legal').first
p sets
```

I am expecting to retrieve specific data from the Pokemon TCG API which from above should be within these Ruby classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p sets.images.symbol` will print out the link to:

```
"https://images.pokemontcg.io/swshp/symbol.png"
```

`p sets.images.logo` will print out the link to:

```
"https://images.pokemontcg.io/swshp/logo.png"
```

When you are unsure what is contained within the class you're getting, in this case a `Pokemon::Set` class, you may see all the methods of this resulting variable with `sets.methods.sort.each{|m| p m}`, there you'll find the **images** method and can dig deeper to **symbol** and **logo**.

In your example you are searching for sets. In case of cards:

```
cards = Pokemon::Card.where(page: 5, pageSize: 100)
cards.each{|card| p card.images.large}
```

This will print out all the links to large cards.

---

#### Update

<sub>Clarification based on comments</sub>

How to print out methods and how to know which class you are referring to.
Let's start with you code snippet:

```ruby
sets = Pokemon::Set.where(q: 'legalities.standard:legal').first
puts sets.class
```

###### Output:

```console
Pokemon::Set
```

It would be more clear if you name your variable as `set` because you're selecting the `.first` element of an array.

Back to my cards example:

```ruby
cards = Pokemon::Card.where(page: 5, pageSize: 100)
puts cards.class
```

###### Output:

```console
Array
```

As I did not select any item from the **array** `cards` naming makes perfect sense, and this array will contain a `card`:

```ruby
card = cards.first
puts card.class
```

###### Output

```console
Pokemon::Card
```

##### Printing methods

So, given we are now well aware of **class** each variable contains and what we are referring to, we are ready to print out the methods for both:

```
sets.methods.sort.each{|method| p method}
cards[0].methods.sort.each{|method| p method}
```

###### Output:

```console
…
:hash
:hp
:hp=
:id
:id=
:images       <== Here!
:images=
:inspect
:instance_eval
:instance_exec
:instance_of?
…
```

Once again, mind the `[0]` selection of the first item. When we want to know methods, we want to know it either for `Pokemon::Set` or `Pokemon::Card`.

Comment: Hey, I could not see the images method, can you show me how you found that.

Comment: I am doing as you suggested like the below but I cannot see the associated methods with the class. ``` cards = Pokemon::CardImages
cards.methods.sort.each do |m|
  p m
end```

Comment: @mustafaalomer711 Hi. this way you are getting methods for the array. Mind your code first, you name the variable `sets` though you use the `.first` selector which selects the first item on the array. Variable should be called a `set` in this case. Back to `cards`, in my example I get the array, you can see it with `p cards.class`. To get methods for `Pokemon::Card` you have to select some item on the array to get its methods. E.g. `cards[0].methods.sort.each{|m| p m}` this will print methods for a single *card* and `:images` will certainly be there.

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful with any class that I need to know the methods for. I appreciate it.

Comment: @mustafaalomer711 so… should we consider it a full answer?

Comment: Sorry , I am new to stack overflow, what shall I post in the answer your question part exactly to get this closed off.